# After Setting Radio Button's value its change event is not working

Tags: jquery

This is the code of radio button

```
                    <div class="col-md-6">

                        <div class="form-group">

                            <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" value="0" name="EditDepositType">نقد</label>

                            <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" value="1" name="EditDepositType">چیک</label>

                        </div>

                    </div>



                </div>
```

Setting its value From DB

```
$('input[name=EditDepositType]').val(DepositType).prop('checked','true');
```

Its Change Event

```
$('input[type=radio][name=EditDepositType]').change(function() {
    if (this.value === '1') {
        $('.chequeData5').show();
        $('.chequeData3').show();
        $('.chequeData4').show();
    }
    else{
        $('.chequeData5').hide();
        $('.chequeData3').hide();
        $('.chequeData4').hide();
    }

});
```

When i check radio buttons after setting its value through inspect element both radio buttons have same value [image: Check Image]

Answer (score 0):

Event will not be trigger when `checked` state is modified programmatically. You need to [`.trigger('change')`](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) manually.

```
$('input[name=EditDepositType]').val(DepositType)
  .prop('checked',true)
  .trigger('change');
```